# How to call Dynamic stored procedure in Asp.Net (Core) Code First?

Tags: asp.net-core, stored-procedures, migration, ef-code-first

I have dynamic stored procedures in my sql database. How can i call it in Asp.Net (Core) Code First?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic stored procedures"?

Comment: dynamic stored procedures are those in which the "Where" condition is complex and change according to search criteria.

Comment: Ok, in that case you call them the same way you call any other stored procedure.